# d3 donut chart with labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am new to d3.js any one help me ,I want donut revenue chart with total value at centre with two label separate outside circle.but ,I cannot add one more label outside the circle and middle total value.
Here is my code,

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <div id="pie-chart"></div>

<script>

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    var w = 650;
    var h = 400;
    var r = 100;
    var ir = 75;
    var textOffset = 24;
    var tweenDuration = 1050;

    //OBJECTS TO BE POPULATED WITH DATA LATER
    var lines, valueLabels, nameLabels;
    var pieData = [];    
    var oldPieData = [];
    var filteredPieData = [];

    //D3 helper function to populate pie slice parameters from array data
    var donut = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){
      return d.itemValue;
    });

    //D3 helper function to create colors from an ordinal scale
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    //D3 helper function to draw arcs, populates parameter "d" in path object
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d){ return d.startAngle; })
      .endAngle(function(d){ return d.endAngle; })
      .innerRadius(ir)
      .outerRadius(r);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GENERATE FAKE DATA /////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var data;
    var dataStructure = [
       {
          "data":[
             {

                "itemLabel":"Suv",

                "itemValue":7165.0
             },
             {

                "itemLabel":"Sedans",
                "itemValue":2430.0
             },
             {

                 "itemLabel":"Hatchback",
                "itemValue":1998.0
             },
             {

                "itemLabel":"VAN",
                "itemValue": 898.0

             },
          ],
          "label":"2007"
       }, 
    ];

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CREATE VIS & GROUPS ////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var vis = d3.select("#pie-chart").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    //GROUP FOR ARCS/PATHS
    var arc_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //GROUP FOR LABELS
    var label_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "label_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //GROUP FOR CENTER TEXT  
    var center_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "center_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //PLACEHOLDER GRAY CIRCLE
    // var paths = arc_group.append("svg:circle")
    //     .attr("fill", "#EFEFEF")
    //     .attr("r", r);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CENTER TEXT ////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //WHITE CIRCLE BEHIND LABELS
    var whiteCircle = center_group.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("r", ir);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STREAKER CONNECTION ////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // to run each time data is generated
    function update(number) {

      data = dataStructure[number].data;

      oldPieData = filteredPieData;
      pieData = donut(data);

      var sliceProportion = 0; //size of this slice
      filteredPieData = pieData.filter(filterData);
      function filterData(element, index, array) {
        element.name = data[index].itemLabel;
        element.value = data[index].itemValue;
        sliceProportion += element.value;
        return (element.value > 0);
      }

        //DRAW ARC PATHS
        paths = arc_group.selectAll("path").data(filteredPieData);
        paths.enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("stroke", "white")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", pieTween);
        paths
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", pieTween);
        paths.exit()
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", removePieTween)
          .remove();

    paths.on("mousemove", function(d){
        div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
              div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
              div.style("display", "inline-block");
        div.html((d.data.itemLabel)+"<br>"+(d.data.itemValue));
    });

    paths.on("mouseout", function(d){
        div.style("display", "none");
    });




        //DRAW TICK MARK LINES FOR LABELS
        lines = label_group.selectAll("line").data(filteredPieData);
        lines.enter().append("svg:line")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("x2", 0)
          .attr("y1", -r-3)
          .attr("y2", -r-18)
          .attr("stroke", "gray")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 * (180/Math.PI) + ")";
          });
        lines.transition()
          .duration(tweenDuration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 * (180/Math.PI) + ")";
          });
        lines.exit().remove();
    //DRAW LABELS WITH PERCENTAGE VALUES
        valueLabels = label_group.selectAll("text.value").data(filteredPieData)
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 5;
            } else {
              return -7;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ( (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ){
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          })
          .text(function(d){
            var percentage = (d.value/sliceProportion)*100;
            return percentage.toFixed(1) + "%";
          });

        valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
          .attr("class", "value")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + Math.cos(((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2)) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2) * (r+textOffset) + ")";
          })
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 5;
            } else {
              return -7;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ( (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ){
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            var percentage = (d.value/sliceProportion)*100;
            return percentage.toFixed(1) + "%";
          });
        valueLabels.transition().duration(tweenDuration).attrTween("transform", textTween);

        valueLabels.exit().remove();

        //DRAW LABELS WITH ENTITY NAMES
        nameLabels = label_group.selectAll("text.units").data(filteredPieData)
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 17;
            } else {
              return 5;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ) {
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            return d.name;
          });

        nameLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
          .attr("class", "units")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + Math.cos(((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2)) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2) * (r+textOffset) + ")";
          })
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 18;
            } else {
              return 5;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ) {
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            return d.name;
          });

        nameLabels.transition().duration(tweenDuration).attrTween("transform", textTween);

        nameLabels.exit().remove();

    }



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////           
    // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function pieTween(d, i) {
      var s0;
      var e0;
      if(oldPieData[i]){
        s0 = oldPieData[i].startAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i].endAngle;
      } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
        s0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
      } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0){
        s0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
      } else {
        s0 = 0;
        e0 = 0;
      }
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle});
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        return arc(b);
      };


    }

    function removePieTween(d, i) {
      s0 = 2 * Math.PI;
      e0 = 2 * Math.PI;
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}, {startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0});
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        return arc(b);
      };
    }

    function textTween(d, i) {
      var a;
      if(oldPieData[i]){
        a = (oldPieData[i].startAngle + oldPieData[i].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
        a = (oldPieData[i-1].startAngle + oldPieData[i-1].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0) {
        a = (oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].startAngle + oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else {
        a = 0;
      }
      var b = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2;

      var fn = d3.interpolateNumber(a, b);
      return function(t) {
        var val = fn(t);
        return "translate(" + Math.cos(val) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin(val) * (r+textOffset) + ")";


      };

    }
    update(0);
    </script>



    css:
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    #pie-chart {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      /*border: 1px solid gray;*/
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      height: 400px;
      text-shadow: none;
      width: 650px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
    #pie-chart .total{
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #pie-chart .units{
      fill: gray;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #pie-chart .label{
      fill: #CCC;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #pie-chart .value{
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #slider label {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .toolTip {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
        color: black;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    var w = 650;
    var h = 400;
    var r = 100;
    var ir = 75;
    var textOffset = 24;
    var tweenDuration = 1050;

    //OBJECTS TO BE POPULATED WITH DATA LATER
    var lines, valueLabels, nameLabels;
    var pieData = [];    
    var oldPieData = [];
    var filteredPieData = [];

    //D3 helper function to populate pie slice parameters from array data
    var donut = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){
      return d.itemValue;
    });

    //D3 helper function to create colors from an ordinal scale
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    //D3 helper function to draw arcs, populates parameter "d" in path object
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d){ return d.startAngle; })
      .endAngle(function(d){ return d.endAngle; })
      .innerRadius(ir)
      .outerRadius(r);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GENERATE FAKE DATA /////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var data;
    var dataStructure = [
       {
          "data":[
             {

                "itemLabel":"Suv",

                "itemValue":7165.0
             },
             {

                "itemLabel":"Sedans",
                "itemValue":2430.0
             },
             {

                 "itemLabel":"Hatchback",
                "itemValue":1998.0
             },
             {

                "itemLabel":"VAN",
                "itemValue": 898.0

             },
          ],
          "label":"2007"
       }, 
    ];

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CREATE VIS & GROUPS ////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var vis = d3.select("#pie-chart").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    //GROUP FOR ARCS/PATHS
    var arc_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //GROUP FOR LABELS
    var label_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "label_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //GROUP FOR CENTER TEXT  
    var center_group = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "center_group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

    //PLACEHOLDER GRAY CIRCLE
    // var paths = arc_group.append("svg:circle")
    //     .attr("fill", "#EFEFEF")
    //     .attr("r", r);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CENTER TEXT ////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //WHITE CIRCLE BEHIND LABELS
    var whiteCircle = center_group.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("r", ir);
    var centerText='';
  

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STREAKER CONNECTION ////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // to run each time data is generated
    function update(number) {

      data = dataStructure[number].data;

      oldPieData = filteredPieData;
      pieData = donut(data);

      var sliceProportion = 0; //size of this slice
      filteredPieData = pieData.filter(filterData);
      function filterData(element, index, array) {
        element.name = data[index].itemLabel;
        element.value = data[index].itemValue;
        sliceProportion += element.value;
        return (element.value > 0);
      }

        //DRAW ARC PATHS
        paths = arc_group.selectAll("path").data(filteredPieData);
        paths.enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("stroke", "white")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", pieTween);
        paths
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", pieTween);
        paths.exit()
          .transition()
            .duration(tweenDuration)
            .attrTween("d", removePieTween)
          .remove();

    paths.on("mousemove", function(d){
        div.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
              div.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
              div.style("display", "inline-block");
        div.html((d.data.itemLabel)+"<br>"+(d.data.itemValue));
      
    });

    paths.on("mouseout", function(d){
        div.style("display", "none");
    });




        //DRAW TICK MARK LINES FOR LABELS
        lines = label_group.selectAll("line").data(filteredPieData);
        lines.enter().append("svg:line")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("x2", 0)
          .attr("y1", -r-3)
          .attr("y2", -r-18)
          .attr("stroke", "gray")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 * (180/Math.PI) + ")";
          });
        lines.transition()
          .duration(tweenDuration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 * (180/Math.PI) + ")";
          });
        lines.exit().remove();
    //DRAW LABELS WITH PERCENTAGE VALUES
        valueLabels = label_group.selectAll("text.value").data(filteredPieData)
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 5;
            } else {
              return -7;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ( (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ){
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          })
          .text(function(d){
            var percentage = (d.value/sliceProportion)*100;
            return percentage.toFixed(1) + "%";
          });

        valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
          .attr("class", "value")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + Math.cos(((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2)) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2) * (r+textOffset) + ")";
          })
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 5;
            } else {
              return -7;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ( (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ){
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            var percentage = (d.value/sliceProportion)*100;
            return "trips: "+percentage.toFixed(1);
 });
        valueLabels.transition().duration(tweenDuration).attrTween("transform", textTween);

        valueLabels.exit().remove();

        //DRAW LABELS WITH ENTITY NAMES
        nameLabels = label_group.selectAll("text.units").data(filteredPieData)
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 17;
            } else {
              return 5;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ) {
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            return d.name;
          });

        nameLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
          .attr("class", "units")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + Math.cos(((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2)) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin((d.startAngle+d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2) * (r+textOffset) + ")";
          })
          .attr("dy", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 > Math.PI/2 && (d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI*1.5 ) {
              return 18;
            } else {
              return 5;
            }
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
            if ((d.startAngle+d.endAngle)/2 < Math.PI ) {
              return "beginning";
            } else {
              return "end";
            }
          }).text(function(d){
            return d.name;
          });

        nameLabels.transition().duration(tweenDuration).attrTween("transform", textTween);

        nameLabels.exit().remove();
   var total = 0;
  pieData.forEach(function(d){ total+=(d.value*1); });
  center_group.selectAll('text').data([total]).enter().append('text').text(function(d){
        return d;
        }).attr('class','value').attr('dy', 8).attr('text-anchor', 'end').attr('transform', 'translate(20, 0)');
    }



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////           
    // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function pieTween(d, i) {
      var s0;
      var e0;
      if(oldPieData[i]){
        s0 = oldPieData[i].startAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i].endAngle;
      } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
        s0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
      } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0){
        s0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
      } else {
        s0 = 0;
        e0 = 0;
      }
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle});
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        return arc(b);
      };


    }

    function removePieTween(d, i) {
      s0 = 2 * Math.PI;
      e0 = 2 * Math.PI;
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}, {startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0});
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        return arc(b);
      };
    }

    function textTween(d, i) {
      var a;
      if(oldPieData[i]){
        a = (oldPieData[i].startAngle + oldPieData[i].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
        a = (oldPieData[i-1].startAngle + oldPieData[i-1].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0) {
        a = (oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].startAngle + oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle - Math.PI)/2;
      } else {
        a = 0;
      }
      var b = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle - Math.PI)/2;

      var fn = d3.interpolateNumber(a, b);
      return function(t) {
        var val = fn(t);
        return "translate(" + Math.cos(val) * (r+textOffset) + "," + Math.sin(val) * (r+textOffset) + ")";


      };

    }
    update(0);
```

```css
body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    #pie-chart {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      /*border: 1px solid gray;*/
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      height: 400px;
      text-shadow: none;
      width: 650px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
    #pie-chart .total{
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #pie-chart .units{
      fill: gray;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #pie-chart .label{
      fill: #CCC;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #pie-chart .value{
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #slider label {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .toolTip {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
        color: black;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie-chart"></div>
```

Modified according to requirement....
After modification.....

Now Check out the code.
I think you are looking for this,,,
If not ask me for more.

Comment: thanks  for replying . text in center is correct ,but i want total item value instead of that,then i want one more label same as like van,hatchback suv,sedans instead of that percentage value showing outside  of circle

Comment: Oh...
Okay,
So you want to display or update the value of the item(van, hatchback suv, sedans) in the center of the circle.
Am I right...
Wait.

Comment: I have modified my answer, check it once.

Comment: I checked but its showing the same result like before its not showing the sum of the values

Comment: You want to see total value - 7165+2430+1998+898=12491 in the center of the circle along with a label SUV or Sedans like this.....
aaaah???

Comment: can we add separate label instead of percentage values that showing outside the circle

Comment: yes, we can add whatever we want, tell me what you want to show....

I didn't get you about adding separate label, 
separate label in the sense.....??