# Label for d3 donut chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am creating donut chart using d3 js. I am trying to add angle label to the arc as shown in the image below

[image]

Here is my working code

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#6fc9e1", "#00627d", "#179bbf"]);

var biggestarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 60);

var bigarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 50);

var smallarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);
    
/*var biggerarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);*/



var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.percent;
});

var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



data = [{
    "label": "Biggest",
        "percent": 33
}, {
    "label": "Big",
    "percent": 17
}, {
    "label": "Small",
    "percent": 50
}]

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    
    if (d.data.label == "Biggest") {
        return biggestarc(d);

    } else if (d.data.label == "Big") {
        return bigarc(d);

    } else {
        
        return smallarc(d);
    }
})

 

.style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
});
g.append("text")                                     //add a label to each slice
                .attr("transform", function(d) {  
                  //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius;
                if (d.data.label == "Biggest") {
                    return "translate(" + biggestarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                else if (d.data.label == "Big") {
                    return "translate(" + bigarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                else{
                    return "translate(" + smallarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                      
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle") 
            .text(function(d, i) { 
              
              return data[i].percent + '%';
               
              
            })
```

```css
body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
}
text {
    font-size:12px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut"></div>
```

Just got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314069/d3-donut-chart-with-labels) link and trying to achieve. Struggling to do that as I'm exploring d3 js. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I think [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/1984c7f2b446fffeedde) should be helpful. If not, let me know, I'll help you out.

Comment: @Shashank thanks for the link. Couldn't do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating all the required co-ordinates will help you draw the labels and pointers (`path`) at the correct positions.

I was about to answer another a similar question: [Donut labels with connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302616/d3-donut-chart-with-connectors#answer-48302798)

Instead of again providing you with links, here's a code snippet using that approach (I think it's simpler than the `polyline` approach I mentioned earlier.

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#6fc9e1", "#00627d", "#179bbf"]);

var biggestarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 60);

var bigarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 50);

var smallarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);
    
/*var biggerarc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);*/



var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.percent;
});

var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



data = [{
    "label": "Biggest",
        "percent": 33
}, {
    "label": "Big",
    "percent": 17
}, {
    "label": "Small",
    "percent": 50
}]

var piedata = pie(data);

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(piedata)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    
    if (d.data.label == "Biggest") {
        return biggestarc(d);

    } else if (d.data.label == "Big") {
        return bigarc(d);

    } else {
        
        return smallarc(d);
    }
}).style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
});

g.append("text")                                     //add a label to each slice
                .attr("transform", function(d) {  
                  //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius;
                if (d.data.label == "Biggest") {
                    return "translate(" + biggestarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                else if (d.data.label == "Big") {
                    return "translate(" + bigarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                else{
                    return "translate(" + smallarc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
            
                }
                      
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle") 
            .text(function(d, i) { 
              
              return data[i].percent + '%';
               
              
            });
            

var labels = g.append('g').classed('labels', true);

labels.selectAll("text").data(piedata)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.label; })
    .each(function(d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
    });

/* labels.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("refX", 3)
    .attr("refY", 3)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 3)
    .attr("cy", 3)
    .attr("r", 3); */

labels.selectAll("path.pointer").data(piedata).enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "pointer")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        } else {
            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        }
    });
```

```css
body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
}
text {
    font-size:12px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="donut"></div>
```

1. The code consists of markers too (which I've commented for now). Try uncommenting if that's an addition you wouldn't mind.
2. Style the connectors as you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @shashank