# D3 Donut Chart with Connectors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to create a static d3 donut chart with labels and connectors from a json object. I've been able to get it to work with an array in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1196/) but can't get the connectors or label text to appear with the data object that I need.

The donut chart is working and the labels are appearing with the percentages, but I need them to appear with the labels and connectors. I think that it has something to do with the way that I am trying to map the connectors but can't figure out the error.

Code is below and also here is a link to a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hef1u71o/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [{
    percentage: 19,
    label: 'Consulting'
  },{
    percentage: 3,
    label: 'Consumer Goods'
  },{
    percentage: 5,
    label: 'Energy/Chemical/Gas'
  },{
    percentage: 3,
    label: 'Entrepreneurship'
  },{
    percentage: 1,
    label: 'Environment & Sustainability'
  },{
    percentage: 19,
    label: 'Financial Services'
  },{
    percentage: 3,
    label: 'General Management'
  },{
    percentage: 6,
    label: 'Government'
  },{
    percentage: 7,
    label: 'Hospital/Health Care/Health Services'
  },{
    percentage: 2,
    label: 'Human Resources'
  },{
    percentage: 4,
    label: 'IT'
  },{
    percentage: 2,
    label: 'International Development'
  },{
    percentage: 3,
    label: 'Manufacturing/Operations'
  },{
    percentage: 4,
    label: 'Marketing/PR/Advertising'
  },{
    percentage: 1,
    label: 'Media/Sports/Entertainment'
  },{
    percentage: 7,
    label: 'Nonprofit/Education/Special Org.'
  },{
    percentage: 6,
    label: 'Other'
  },{
    percentage: 2,
    label: 'Research & Development'
  },{
    percentage: 4,
    label: 'Sales/Business Development'
  },];


var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#243668", "#2b7eb4", "#186b97", "#6391a1", "#d2c5b7", "#9c9286", "#5b5b59"]);


  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { return d.percentage; });


var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
.data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);

svg.selectAll("text").data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
    });

svg.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("refX", 3)
    .attr("refY", 3)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 3)
    .attr("cy", 3)
    .attr("r", 3);

svg.selectAll("path.pointer").data(pie(data)).enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "pointer")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        } else {
            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        }
    });


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your data into variable:

```
var pieData = pie(data);
```

And use this variable here:

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(pieData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d) { // !!! you extent the dataset here 
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
    });
```

and here:

```
svg.selectAll("path.pointer").data(pieData).enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "pointer")
...
```

It's important because of you extend the data (see `each` method). You will use extended properties for calculating of connectors position and you should use the same dataset for both cases.

Check [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4hsbt7k5/).

Comment: I was just about to post the same. :)